# How to migrate a Debian DOS partitioned VM to GUID for partitions > 2 TB

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, vmware

we have a outdated Debian 10 VM with DOS partition and 2 * 2 TB Partitions.

How is the elegantest way to migrate to Partition schema GUID so that we have
one 4 TB Partition and optionally make it bigger

Booting live distro and backup?
This would need to include a Synology we have in fstab.
Reinstall and restore?
or
Create a new drive/container, mount it, boot gparted and copy file-systems?

Exanding a partition with VMWare is a well known process for us -> gparted

Answer (score 2):

GPT on the system disk typically goes with UEFI, but I don't know anything about VMware's UEFI capabilities, so I will assume for now that the VM will remain set to the BIOS/legacy boot method. (Windows wouldn't like it, but Linux can boot in this configuration without problems).

1. Use `gdisk` to transform the current partition table to GPT.
2. Shrink a partition to make some free space (just 2 MB) for a new "BIOS Boot Partition" that is used by GRUB. As this will be accessed via BIOS calls, it should ideally be near the beginning of the disk.
3. Create that new "BIOS Boot Partition".

   - If using GParted, do not select any filesystem (just an empty partition), but set the `bios_grub` flag on the partition.
   - If using gdisk, select `ef02` as the partition type.
4. Re-run `grub-install` and `update-grub`.

If however you decide to convert the VM to UEFI at the same time, the process is slightly different:

- In steps 2 and 3, you will need a much larger "EFI System Partition" (at least 100 MB), which has the GParted flag `esp` or the gdisk type `ef00`. It must be formatted using FAT32 and mounted at `/boot/efi` (Debian prefers it there).
- Before doing step 4 you will need to install the "grub-efi-amd64" package, and perhaps clean out the old BIOS-specific "i386-pc" files from /boot/grub.

Comment: The last (in terms of LBA) partition (filesystem included) often needs to be slightly shrinked before the transformation can be done.

Comment: And the logical conclusion: It's much easier, faster and with likely better results to just backup files and settings from the old one and create and install fresh with the desired VM settings and then copy back the files and user settings, if applicable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: If you think that is the conclusion, please post it as your own answer instead.

Comment: @user1686 But it's not an answer? The question is valid "as is" and your excellent answer is to the point of what's being asked. My comment is merely a suggestion to do things differently, not really an answer. Now, if what's being asked was impossible or so convoluted to the point of being, in practice, undoable, that would be a different scenario, one where it would make sense to "answer" with an alternative and a justification to why it can't be done.

Comment: The answer is very good for me at the moment. I had to add some stuff. I am doing a test case. The shrinking/moving of a 2 TB partition takes 3,5 hours alone. At the moment i am deleting snapshots which typically needs more time than the original work. I will report...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your excellent answer!

I had to combine it with the important info from [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235362/trying-to-reinstall-grub-2-cannot-find-a-device-for-boot-is-dev-mounted)

mount /dev/sdaN /mnt
mount --rbind /dev  /mnt/dev
mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --rbind /sys  /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt bash
mount /dev/sdaN /
grub-install /dev/sda